# Change every word with TamperMonkey

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I want to get every word or every sentence (not HTML code) from the page, then send it to the server via POST, get response and change that word/sentence/whole text with the response.

My code runs after click from TamperMonkey context menu:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        name
// @namespace   https://github.com/...
// @version 1.0
// @description description
// @copyright 2016+, 31SDS14
// @grant      unsafeWindow
// @grant      GM_registerMenuCommand
// ==/UserScript==

GM_registerMenuCommand('Change that words!', function() { 
    alert(document.body.innerHTML);
    //here send every word or whole sentences to the server via POST and replace those words with received response
}, 'r');
```

How can I get text from the body without HTML code?

Comment: I can get code from the html body using document.body.innerHTML but I don't know how to get only text without HTML.

Comment: Actually, maybe I asked too much, POST requests aren't necessary right now. I only want to know how to get text without HTML.

Comment: This seems too simple :) Use `document.body.innerText` instead.

Comment: Would you mind accepting my answer then? :)

Comment: Yes, of course, I needed to wait 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple answer is:

```
document.body.innerText;
```